# Keypress redirect issue

Tags: jquery, keypress

I have this code for redirecting when a key is pressed:

```
$('body').bind('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 66) { 
        window.location = "page.php"; 
    }
});
```

I have this but repeated for about 10 different keys.

My question is, how can i make it not applicable if the user has text highlighted with the mouse- example, if he is copy or pasting with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: i think you area looking for `event.metaKey` i think it is mapped for cross browser compatibility. but there are also `ctrlKey` and `altKey` in the event object. But i don't have time right now to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Check for both selected text and the key :

```
$('body').on('keyup', function(event) {
   var t = '';
   if(window.getSelection){
       t = window.getSelection();
   }else if(document.getSelection){
       t = document.getSelection();
   }else if(document.selection){
       t = document.selection.createRange().text;
   }
   if ((!t.length) && event.which==66) window.location = 'page.php';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Obviously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828802/1225328), there is no `isKeyDown()` function in JS. That said, this should suit your needs though:

```js
function noMetakeyPressed(metakeysPressed) {
    for (var k in metakeysPressed) {
        if (metakeysPressed[k]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var metakeysPressed = {17: false, 18: false};

$('body')
.bind('keydown', function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
    case 17: // Ctrl
    case 18: // Alt
        metakeysPressed[event.keyCode] = true;
        break;
    case 66: // B
        if (noMetakeyPressed(metakeysPressed)) {
            alert("B pressed");
        }
        break;
    }
})
.bind('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 17 || event.keyCode == 18) {
        metakeysPressed[event.keyCode] = false;
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krw7X/)

You could also use a single `isMetakeyPressed` boolean variable, but maybe you need to know what *metakey* is currently pressed.