# KeyboardState.pressed is always true after .prompt or alert - Why?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, alert, prompt

As the title says, I have tried THREEx and Stemkovskis standalone KeyboardState.js , and neither of them seems to update properly.

This is my code:

```
m_vKeyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
// m_vKeyboard.update(); // if using stemkovskis
if (m_vKeyboard.pressed("F")) {
    alert("And now it is always true!");
}
```

you click the F key once, release it; alert window pops up, click OK, it pops up again for all eternity. How come?

Comment: Anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many browsers repeat `keydown`. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828802) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) `(ctrl+f : auto-repeat)`.

Here's a proposed solution for your specific problem :

A. when `keydown` store its state as `true` in some array and make it false on `keyup`.

```
wasPressed['F'] = true;  //on keydown
wasPressed['F'] = false; //on keyup
```

B. when checking for next `keydown` check its state as well.

```
if (m_vKeyboard.pressed("F") && !wasPressed['F'])
```

Find full implementation : [Here](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.keyboardstate/blob/master/examples/norepeatkeydown.html#L35)

**UPDATE**

```
var wasPressed  = {};
if( keyboard.pressed('F')  && !wasPressed['f'] ){
            alert("F was pressed");
            prompt("Enter data : ");
            wasPressed['f'] = true;         
        }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
keyboard.domElement.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
            wasPressed  = {};
    })
```

Comment: I haven't tried your solution but I do not think it will work. Since when I click on 'F', I use prompt which locks the code (aka when I release 'F' it will not trigger the onKeyUp) therefor its always true. I've looked at your code, how does it check if a button on the keyboard is currently pressed?

Comment: I tried with prompt(see update) and it works just fine.

Comment: Well of course it works, you set the boolean to true (that's how I have solved it right now).

What happends if you click on F a second time just after you closed the prompt?

Comment: Works but feels like a cheap way to do it ;) Cheers though! Wanted a solution for this for a while now!

Comment: I know! it really is a cheap workaround. But for a quick solution, it seems like the best! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if it has something to do with alert() being a blocking call.  Using the code below gives me your same issue.  If I comment out the alert() and un-comment the console.log() it seems to work fine.  However, I'm not sure if that helps your issue.

```
    var m_vKeyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();

    setInterval(function () {
        var key = "F";
        var pressed = m_vKeyboard.pressed(key);
        alert("And now it is always true!");
        //console.log("key", key, "pressed", pressed);
    }, 100);
```

Comment: Well yes, commenting it solves the "always" true problem. However, I want to use promt to have a user insert a INT value to use in an algorithm. Perhaps there is some other way?

Comment: Yeah, using alert(), prompt(), and confirm() are problematic.  Can you not use jQuery or other library for prompting so that you aren't calling blocking type functions?

Comment: I problem is that I can't have the rest of the webpage rolling in the background so a blocking call is needed I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the beginning of `onKeyDown` in KeyboardState.js:

```
if (event.repeat) return;
```