# How to prevent Chrome open history after press CTRL+H

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I mean is there any way to prevent the default accesskey in Chrome.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
text.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 72) {
    // do something...
    alert("You wont see me cause Chrome will open history manager");
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You need Keydown Event.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
text.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
 console.log(e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 72 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Stopped');
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added `isCtrlDown` variable and `keyup` with `keydown` event, to achieve what you're looking for because I didn't see `isKeyDown` kind of function in Key as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828613/check-if-a-key-is-down).

```
var isCtrlDown = false;
var text = document.getElementById("text");
text.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 17){
        isCtrlDown = true;
    }
    if(isCtrlDown && e.keyCode == 72){
        // do something...
        console.log("You wont see me cause Chrome will open history manager");
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
text.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 17){
        isCtrlDown = false;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```