# Scroll div using Arrow down key not works

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to scroll a div with keydown event in Reactjs.
When user presses the arrow down key I set the scrollTop value like this:

```
 const onKeyDown = e => {
    if (e.key == "ArrowDown") {
    console.log(e)
    var elmnt = document.getElementsById('myDiv');
    elmnt.scrollTop += 40;
      }
    }
```

This work when I press the key just once.
But, when I hold the key down, elmnt scrollTop not change.
According to the number of event logs, the number of handleKeyDown runs are OK.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1828613/10221765