# Handle VueJS event only when key is pressed

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I use VueJS component provided by 3rd-party library, which has its own events. I can handle such events as usual with "v-on" directive and specifying interesting event name, like that:

```
<TheComponent v-on:itemchanged="handler"/>
```

But is it possible to run handler only when 'itemchanged' occurs with CTRL key pressed? The handler should not run when CTRL key is not pressed.

I tried to play with click.crtl and keydown.ctrl but have no success.

Comment: I found a semi-working solution, I wrapped component into outer div with `v-on:click.ctrl="pressed = true"`. Next in nested component's handler i'm checking 'pressed' variable. It works but only from second click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to run handler only when 'itemchanged' occurs with CTRL key pressed?

Assuming `itemchanged` is triggered by a `change` event: no, not without a workaround.  Unlike keyboard and mouse events, `change` contains no keyboard info.  You'll need to track the status of ctrl keypresses independently because [JavaScript has no way of testing whether a key is down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828613/check-if-a-key-is-down) outside of those events.

**Plugin**

One encapsulated way to accomplish it is with a plugin:

```js
const pluginKeypresses = function(Vue) {
  const keyPresses = {
    Control: false
  }
  window.onkeyup = function(e) { keyPresses[e.key] = false; }
  window.onkeydown = function(e) { keyPresses[e.key] = true; }
  Vue.prototype.$keyPresses = Vue.observable(keyPresses);
}
Vue.use(pluginKeypresses);
```

<sub>*Note: The `e.key` detection here is the current standard as of 11/2020, but is [not yet fully supported by IE and some other browsers](https://caniuse.com/keyboardevent-code). If IE matters to you, change the [key detection implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/keycode-vs-which) to your liking.*</sub>

**Usage**

From anywhere in the app you can test `this.$keyPresses.Control` (boolean)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/hLyfrk7s)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you receive an event object with this event ? By adding a parameter to `handler` you should be able to catch the event, and check inside which key is pressed. Then just add a `if` statement at the beginning of you handler function.

Comment: If an appropriate keyboard event `$event` had been passed, then `.ctrl` would have worked

Comment: yes, i receive event object, but if using "v-on:itemchanged", it doesn't contain any info about pressed keys. If I try to modify it to "v-on:itemchanged.ctrl" or "v-on:click.ctrl" it is not working. At the same time "v-on:click.ctrl" works on simple div element. So I think this component might not support key-based events.

Comment: @lesovsky This is likely because the event is a `change` event, which has no keyboard information