# How to detect click+specific key press in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and learning event handlers. How to detect *click + specific* key pressed concurrently? For example `click+D`, using pure (vanilla) js.

Edit:
I tried this way but its not detecting the click event when key is pressed.
The `console.log("key "+keyPressed)` statement is also executed continuously while key is in pressed state.

```
keyPressed=false;

function keyDown(event) {
    var x = event.key;
  
    if (x == "a" || x == "A") { 
         keyPressed=true;
         console.log("key "+keyPressed);
    }

  }

function keyUp(event){

  keyPressed=false;
  
  console.log("key "+keyPressed);

}

 function clickHelper(event){
  console.log("---");
    if(keyPressed){
      console.log("*****");
    }
 }
```

Comment: You need to track keypresses first and match your condition on click, many examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828613/check-if-a-key-is-down

Answer (score 1):

IIRC you cannot use one event to detect if the mouse is held down AND a button is clicked. However, you can set a property called `mouseDown` of the document and register an event listener for mouse state.

```js
var mouseDown = 0;
document.body.onmousedown = function () {
    ++mouseDown;
};
document.body.onmouseup = function () {
    --mouseDown;
};

document.body.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (mouseDown && e.key === 'd') {
        alert('D was pressed while clicking');
    }
};
```

I used some code from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322827/17914167) for this.