# Making mousemove fire only when user is holding down the left mouse button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm making a 360 degree image viewer (in plain JavaScript) and i'm trying to make it so that when a user mouses left or right over the image it swaps images (creating the 360 effect) but only while they're holding down their mouse button.

I tried using the event's "which" property (equals 1 in Chrome when left mouse button is held but seems to always equal 1 in Safari and Firefox even when the mouse button isn't being held).

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322378/javascript-check-if-mouse-button-down

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript library?

Comment: @Šime Vidas no js library for this project, just good old fashioned vanilla js.

Comment: @codewombat Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: i want to support FF,chrome,safari, and ie 7 - 9

Comment: @codewombat IE7 and 8 have different event API (`attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`). Do you have an utility function for adding event handlers? Or how else are you doing it?

Comment: yes i have a cross browser utility function for this.

Comment: @codewombat Which one? Is it public? Can you post the code? I cannot provide a solution without it...

Comment: @abimelex that works superbly. i guess the real problem here is that when i start dragging in FF it starts letting me drag the image off screen(like when you try to drag an image from the browser to the desktop) is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: detailed here: http://www.develobert.info/2008/10/disable-firefox-image-drag.html

Comment: found the problem: i was using preventDefault() in mousemove instead of mousedown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem: i was using preventDefault() in mousemove instead of mousedown