# Swipe to select checkboxes in a web browser

Tags: jquery, usability

Sometimes our forms have a lot of checkboxes in a table column. The user has to go through and check a bunch of them (but not all of them).

Often I think it would be nice if you could just click and drag across the checkboxes, selecting the ones you want with one swipe.

I haven't seen this implemented before. Does anyone have an opinion on the usability of something like this?

Has anyone seen a jquery plugin that could enable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my answer, which credit to Trufa and Tats for getting the ball rolling: http://jsfiddle.net/ebStc/7/

Here is a plugin for it:

```
$.fn.swipeable = function() {

var mousedownOn = {
        id: '',
        checkState: false
    };

$(document)
    .mouseup(function() {
        mousedownOn.id = '';
    });

$(this)
    .filter(':checkbox')
    .mousedown(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        mousedownOn.id = $this.attr('id');
        mousedownOn.checkState = $this.prop('checked');
        $this.prop('checked',!$this.prop('checked'));
        $this.change();
    })
    .mouseenter(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (mousedownOn.id != '' && mousedownOn.id != $this.attr('id')){
            $this.prop('checked',!mousedownOn.checkState);
            $this.change();
        }
    })
    .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
};
```

Comment: Have any vanilla JS solution?

Answer (score 2):

Like this man? http://jsfiddle.net/ebStc/3/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/ebStc/2/

Please let me know if this helps, or I am happy to remove this post.

Hope it help the cause.

**behaviou** when you will drag your mouse pointer it will get selected and if drag again it will deselect `:)`

**code**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').mouseenter(function() {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
    } else {
         $(this).prop('checked',true);
    }
});​
```

Comment: yes almost, but it would be better if you had to click-and-drag, rather than just waving the mouse

Comment: I think to make it usable you would also need to initially click on one of the checkboxes, rather than just anywhere on the screen

Comment: Hiya @cbp `:)` hmm I can make my own fake event mixing between , click, mousedown, and hover but that will take time `:)` funny thing is `drag` event is there by for div and stuff! `:)` o well you gave my idea for my next plugin. although not sure if there is another event beside mouse enter to fake the drag over - **Plz Note:** `:)` you can tell user that it is drag coz it will select it on mouse enter anyways if that suffice the need. I reckon mouse enter will do the rick :P lemme see / think...

Comment: @Trufa lol NO worries + but yeah ping me if you have better Idea we can write a plugin for an event for this `:)`

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: This is unfinished work and it is based on [Tats answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11409054/463065) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322827/463065).

You can check the live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ebStc/5/).

It think it is what OP wanted but haven't figured out why it is not actually checking the first checkbox when you do a mouse down, but it is close to the mouse drag effect the OP was looking for.

Edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ebStc/6/) is a non ideal solution.

Comment: Yeah cool, that's the behaviour I was looking for. I'll see what I can throw together too. First one past the line gets the 25 points :)