# Issue with mousedown and mouseup event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, drag

I have a drag and drop functionality on a page. I have defined a `mousedown`, `mousemove`, and `mouseup` event handlers to do it. However, sometimes, in the browser (I haven't been able to narrow it down to one because it has happened on all of them at some point), when the user clicks (and lets go) on the object to drag, he is now dragging the object and has to click again (and let go) to release the object.

The intended functionality is for the user to click down and hold while dragging, letting go of the click only when he wants to release the object he is dragging. Is there something I can add inside the `mousemove` handler to check if the `mousedown` is still active?

Comment: Are you using this as an opportunity to learn jQuery? If not, there is no point re-inventing the wheel: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Also a code example of what you are doing may be helpful.

Comment: We're reinventing the wheel :P I jumped into a project that already had it done this way. In the future, we may port everything over to that jquery lib.

Answer (score 0):

It's old but it may still help you I guess. Otherwise just use jQueryUI Drag'n'Drop-Plugin.

[JavaScript: Check if mouse button down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322378/javascript-check-if-mouse-button-down)