# Check if a button is being clicked in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, click, dom-events

Here's my question: I want to see from javascript if an object is being clicked at the moment, Here is an example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (document.getElementByTagName('button')[0].isBeingClicked) { //I know this isn't right: This is where my question is about.
        console.log('Button being clicked');
        return;
    };
    console.log('Button not being clicked');
}, 1000);
```

With as simplified HTML ofcourse:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button>Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

So all together: I want to be able to see whether a button or another object is being clicked at this time. Not if it has been clicked, but is being clicked.

Comment: Define "being clicked"

Comment: Are you looking for the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events?

Comment: It is, Brandon. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

**HTML**

```
<button onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()">Click me</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
var click = false;
function mouseDown() {
    click = true;
    console.log('Button being clicked');
}
function mouseUp() {
    click = false;
    console.log('Button not being clicked');
}
setInterval(function(){
    if (click === false) {  
        console.log('Button not being clicked');
    } else if (click === true) {
        console.log('Button being clicked');
    }
}, 1000)
</script>
```

An alternative solution, and much more in depth answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322378/javascript-check-if-mouse-button-down).

Answer (score 0):

As George stated, you are looking for the mousedown() event. It fires exactly when the click happens not after it's been clicked.

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onmousedown)
```

You are missing the s after elements. It returns an array, Hence the [0]. If this isn't the first button on the page than this won't work, Use the code below if there's more than 1 button,

```
var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(var i=0;i > buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].addEventlistener("mousedown", MyFunction);
}
```

This will call a function called MyFunction on the press of any buttons

Comment: Yes I've tried this, but my aim is to check if a button is being clicked, and not have a function which is being called at a click. So it's kind of the other way around. Thanks anyway!