# How to check if button was Pressed javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this button in HTML and I need to check if the button has been pressed to activate another function or not.

```
<button id="generator" class="button ripple" onclick="myFunction()">Berechnen</button>
```

```js
    function printDiv(print) {
        if(document.getElementById('generator').clicked == true){
            var printContents = document.getElementById(print).innerHTML;
            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
       
            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;   
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
            
        }
        else{
            alert("pls select")
        }
       
   }
```

Comment: You can simply use a flag variable and set it in `click` event handler

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a button is being clicked in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997409/check-if-a-button-is-being-clicked-in-javascript)

Comment: @s.kuznetsov no i have already try it

Comment: @obind, then show the code you tried.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov okay

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a Button is clicked by using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788191/how-to-check-whether-a-button-is-clicked-by-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this function directly on button click:

```
    <div id="printDiv1">Printable Content</div>
<button id="generator" class="button ripple" onclick="printDiv('printDiv1')">Berechnen</button>
<script>
function printDiv(print) {
        //if(document.getElementById('generator').clicked == true){
            var printContents = document.getElementById(print).innerHTML;
            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
       
            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;   
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
            
        //}
       // else{
       //     alert("pls select")
        //}
       
   }
</script>
```

here the variable passed in the method printDiv(print) can be defined earlier or can be id of the div to print.

Comment: i have 2 buttons one to generate and the other one to print. but you can only print after you used one time the generate buttonhow can i make this

Comment: the question was about checking one button click, so I answered for that to directly use onclick. method print.

Comment: if there are 2 buttons, one for generate and 1 for print, you can use 2 functions sending same arguments(div ID)  but 1 button will use generating function, the 2nd button will use printing function onclick.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {

   alert("button was Clicked");

};
```

```html
<h3>Click on button below </h3>
<button id="button"> Click Me! </button>
```