# Specific use of MouseEvent.button and MouseEvent.which

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events

I know one should use both, `event.button` and `event.which` as a safe side for cross-browser compatibility concern.

But still, I am puzzled. I am not able to comprehend the exact context where I should use which mouse event property, `MouseEvent.button` or `MouseEvent.which`, and where should I avoid the one.

Also, the quirks associated with different browsers(eg the values associated with those)

Well organized comprehensive details will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nowadays, you should use `MouseEvent.button*s*` (note the plural "s"), and `.which` is only needed as a fallback on Safari. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48970682/1869660

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which

> Non-standard This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

It seems you shouldn't use MouseEvent.which

I can't find much more information on it

Comment: I somewhere heard that there's also some context where MouseEvent.which is mandatory as MouseEvent.button is not supported or associated with quirks. I couldn't recall exact context. Any advice in this?