# JavaScript / jQuery - Program keeps drawing after mouse left the canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am making a paint application using jQuery and I ran into a problem.

```
CodePen: https://codepen.io/mistahdukk/pen/dmaKOV

canvas.mousedown(function(e){
    down = true;
    draw(e);
}).mouseover(function(e){
    ctx.beginPath();
    draw(e);
}).mouseout(function(e){
    ctx.beginPath();
}).mousemove(draw).mouseup(function(){
    down =false;
    ctx.beginPath();
});
```

If the mouse leaves the canvas and the click is released and the mouse re-enters the canvas, the app will continue to draw, but I only want to make it so that it draws only when the mouse has been clicked. I don't really know how to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If your mouseup event telling it to stop drawing is only set on the canvas it isn't going to register if you mouseup on any other part of the window. Also your code should be in your question itself, there is a reason the editor will tell you that you need to include code

Comment: I've got a comment about your CodePen. I've got my Chrome browser in a small size and the output of the CodePen is with scroll bars. When I scroll down and draw, it is drawing above my cursor. Don't know if that's because of CodePen or your code, but maybe you need to know!

Comment: You may want to upvote helpful answers… It's strange to see an accepted with score 0 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer**

Try this:

```
var mouseDown = 0;
window.onmousedown = function() { 
  ++mouseDown;
}
window.onmouseup = function() {
  --mouseDown;
}

canvas.mousedown(function(e){
    down = true;
    draw(e);
}).mouseover(function(e){
    if(mouseDown) {
      down = true;
    }
    ctx.beginPath();
    draw(e);
}).mouseout(function(e){
    down =false; // <-- What you need to add
    ctx.beginPath();
}).mousemove(draw).mouseup(function(){
    down =false;
    ctx.beginPath();
});
```

Inspired by the solution of this answer: [JavaScript: Check if mouse button down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322378/javascript-check-if-mouse-button-down)

⋅
⋅
⋅

**Old answer**

At the end of you javascript code, you can add `down =false;` on the `mouseout` event to get the same functionality as the `mouseup` event.

```
canvas.mousedown(function(e){
    down = true;
    draw(e);
}).mouseover(function(e){
    ctx.beginPath();
    draw(e);
}).mouseout(function(e){
    down =false; // <-- What you need to add
    ctx.beginPath();
}).mousemove(draw).mouseup(function(){
    down =false;
    ctx.beginPath();
});
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this but I wanted it so that when I re-enter the canvas and the mouse button is still pressed, to continue drawing.

Comment: @MisterDukk Edited with your comment. I hope it helps !

Comment: It does indeed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In your mouse out event you can also set down variable to false....
[copen](https://codepen.io/RACCH/pen/ZxwRqp)

```
canvas.mousedown(function(e){
    down = true;
    draw(e);
}).mouseover(function(e){
    ctx.beginPath();
    draw(e);
}).mouseout(function(e){
  down =false;
    ctx.beginPath();
}).mousemove(draw).mouseup(function(){
    down =false;
    ctx.beginPath();
});
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this but I wanted it so that when I re-enter the canvas and the mouse button is still pressed, to continue drawing

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```js
canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    drawing = false; 
})
```

CSS:

```
body {
    user-select: none; // or even better to your canvas wrapper to disable higlighting once you left click to draw on canvas again
}
```