# Trouble with jquery mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable, drag

I am currently working on making a grid of squares for a tile map. I have it set up so clicking on a tile changes its state to explored from unexplored. I am attempting to have it so that dragging with the mouse down will change the state of all underlying tiles, however I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried using mousedown and mouseup events to set a down boolean value which I then check inside of a mouseover. I have tried going about this in several ways (i.e. the commented out code). The current code will work for clicking but I really want to be able to do a drag to change multiples feature.

```js
var tableString;
var width = 35;
var height = 15;
var cells = [];
var localX;
var localY;


function cell(x, y, c) {
  positionX = x;
  positionY = y;
  category = c;
}

function createMap() {
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      let c = new cell();
      c.category = "unexplored";
      c.positionX = j;
      c.positionY = i;
      row.push(c);
    }
    cells.push(row);
  }
}

function drawMap() {
  tableString = "<table draggable='false'>";
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    tableString += "<tr draggable='false'>";
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      tableString += '<td draggable="false" class="' + cells[i][j].category + '" data-row="' + j + '" data-column="' + i + '"></td>';
    }
    tableString += "</tr>";
  }
  tableString += "</table>";
  $("#mainContainer").html(tableString);
  console.log("drew it");
}

function updateCellCategory(x, y, c) {
  cells[x][y].category = c;
  drawMap();
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  createMap();
  drawMap();


  // var down = false;
  // $(document,"td").mousedown(function () {
  //     down = true;
  // })
  // $(document,"td").mouseup(function () {
  //     down = false;
  // });

  // $(document,"td").on('mouseover','td',function () {
  //     if (down) {
  //         console.log("hovering and holding");
  //         localX = $(this).attr("data-row");
  //         localY = $(this).attr("data-column");
  //         updateCellCategory(localY, localX, "explored");
  //     }

  // });
});


// $(document).on('mousedown',"td, documen",(function () {
//     down = true;
//     console.log(down);
// }));
// $(document).on('mouseup',"*",(function () {
//     down = false;
//     console.log(down);
// }));

// $(document).on('mouseover','td',function () {
//     if (down) {
//         console.log("hovering and holding");
//         localX = $(this).attr("data-row");
//         localY = $(this).attr("data-column");
//         updateCellCategory(localY, localX, "explored");
//     }

// });

$("*").delegate('td', 'click', function() {
  localX = $(this).attr("data-row");
  localY = $(this).attr("data-column");
  updateCellCategory(localY, localX, "explored");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#mainContainer {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

td {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: .05px solid black;
}

.explored {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.unexplored {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The main issue I found when working on this is that some of the commented code works sometimes, but the second a drag event happens on a td the code breaks and the mouseup is not recognized causing the mouse cursur to continue affecting tiles even though the mouse was not held down.

Comment: `delegate` is deprecated. You'd be best to update your code. Also, if you post some of your HTML we might be able to get the above into a working demo.

Comment: I just made it into a codepen
https://codepen.io/JoelSchmidt/pen/VwZEGON

Comment: You don't need to use codepen here. In fact, you'll probably get more help if you insert a code snippet. I've changed your question.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Comment: See my answer. Please add any comments to that. Is that close to what you want?

Comment: I have uncommented a section of your code and it is working for me in Firefox perfectly. Here is the forked code pen. https://codepen.io/ianroskow/pen/WNeaaeR  Look at this post that is using a similar approach, they talk about browser issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322378/javascript-check-if-mouse-button-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Using the `click` event is not what you want, since that involves pressing the mouse **and** releasing it.

Instead use, the `mousemove`, `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. Also, keep track of whether the mouse is down or not using a variable.

```js
var tableString;
var width = 35;
var height = 15;
var cells = [];
var localX;
var localY;
var mouseDown = false;

function cell(x, y, c) {
  positionX = x;
  positionY = y;
  category = c;
}

function createMap() {
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      let c = new cell();
      c.category = "unexplored";
      c.positionX = j;
      c.positionY = i;
      row.push(c);
    }
    cells.push(row);
  }
}

function drawMap() {
  tableString = "<table draggable='false'>";
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    tableString += "<tr draggable='false'>";
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      tableString += '<td draggable="false" class="' + cells[i][j].category + '" data-row="' + j + '" data-column="' + i + '"></td>';
    }
    tableString += "</tr>";
  }
  tableString += "</table>";
  $("#mainContainer").html(tableString);
  //console.log("drew it");
}

function updateCellCategory(x, y, c) {
  cells[x][y].category = c;
  drawMap();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  createMap();
  drawMap();
});

$("*").on("mousedown", 'td',  function() 
{
  mouseDown = true;
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function() 
{
  mouseDown = false;
});

$("*").on("mousemove", 'td',  function() 
{
  if(!mouseDown)
    return;

  localX = $(this).attr("data-row");
  localY = $(this).attr("data-column");
  updateCellCategory(localY, localX, "explored");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#mainContainer {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

td {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: .05px solid black;
}

.explored {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.unexplored {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly! Cant thank you enough!

Comment: No worries. Please set as "answered" if indeed it has.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether or not the mouse is down using the event parameter of the event handler. Look at the last few lines of the snippet.

```js
var tableString;
var width = 35;
var height = 15;
var cells = [];
var localX;
var localY;


function cell(x, y, c) {
  positionX = x;
  positionY = y;
  category = c;
}

function createMap() {
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      let c = new cell();
      c.category = "unexplored";
      c.positionX = j;
      c.positionY = i;
      row.push(c);
    }
    cells.push(row);
  }
}

function drawMap() {
  tableString = "<table draggable='false'>";
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    tableString += "<tr draggable='false'>";
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      tableString += '<td draggable="false" class="' + cells[i][j].category + '" data-row="' + j + '" data-column="' + i + '"></td>';
    }
    tableString += "</tr>";
  }
  tableString += "</table>";
  $("#mainContainer").html(tableString);
  console.log("drew it");
}

function updateCellCategory(x, y, c) {
  cells[x][y].category = c;
  drawMap();
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  createMap();
  drawMap();


  // var down = false;
  // $(document,"td").mousedown(function () {
  //     down = true;
  // })
  // $(document,"td").mouseup(function () {
  //     down = false;
  // });

  // $(document,"td").on('mouseover','td',function () {
  //     if (down) {
  //         console.log("hovering and holding");
  //         localX = $(this).attr("data-row");
  //         localY = $(this).attr("data-column");
  //         updateCellCategory(localY, localX, "explored");
  //     }

  // });
});


// $(document).on('mousedown',"td, documen",(function () {
//     down = true;
//     console.log(down);
// }));
// $(document).on('mouseup',"*",(function () {
//     down = false;
//     console.log(down);
// }));

// $(document).on('mouseover','td',function () {
//     if (down) {
//         console.log("hovering and holding");
//         localX = $(this).attr("data-row");
//         localY = $(this).attr("data-column");
//         updateCellCategory(localY, localX, "explored");
//     }

// });

$("*").delegate('td', 'mousedown', function() {
  localX = $(this).attr("data-row");
  localY = $(this).attr("data-column");
  updateCellCategory(localY, localX, "explored");
});

$("*").delegate('td', 'mouseenter', function(event) {
  if (event.buttons) {
    localX = $(this).attr("data-row");
    localY = $(this).attr("data-column");
    updateCellCategory(localY, localX, "explored");
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#mainContainer {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

td {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: .05px solid black;
}

.explored {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.unexplored {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the first cell that you click down. You have to then move to a different cell...

Comment: @LeeTaylor fixed.