# how to make multiple movable elements

Tags: javascript, html, window, movable

I have this code for creating movable windows (elements), and I call this function when I create a new window:

```js
function dragWindow(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    elmnt.querySelector(".window-caption").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }
    function elementDrag(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }
    function closeDragElement() {
        // alert(elmnt.id);
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

[image]
The problem is:

> if I create a new window, I can't move windows they created before.

Comment: You should call this function when the user clicks on a window

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW that gives me the true answer! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called the function again on each of the windows (in developer console); And it showed me the right answer:
[image]

> So, when I create a new window, I should call dragWindow again for each window.

Answer (score 0):

When you moved up the mouse, function `closeDragElement()` was called and the event listener `document.onmousemove` was overwritten to 'null'.

Comment out the last line in function `closeDragElement()` may solve this problem:

```
function closeDragElement() {
        // alert(elmnt.id);
        document.onmouseup = null;
        // document.onmousemove = null;
}
```

Edit: added an variable `mousedown` to indicate whether the mouse is down.

```
function dragWindow(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    var mousedown = 0;
    elmnt.querySelector(".window-caption").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mousedown++;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }
    function elementDrag(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (mousedown === 0) {return;}
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }
    function closeDragElement() {
        // alert(elmnt.id);
        mousedown--;
        document.onmouseup = null;
        //document.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/322827/8031896

Comment: oh this makes another problem, after mouseup window still moves with mouse move.

Comment: @A.L. Oh, didn't see that coming. The edited version introduced an additional variable to record the mousedown status. Hopefully this will work.